# View full device breakdown in Firebase

Tags: analytics, firebase-analytics

On the Firebase Analytics Dashboard they display summary data for device and OS breakdown but it does not show the complete breakdown (in my case meaning I can't view the breakdown for 44.7% of my user base). Is there anywhere in Firebase I can either view this information or export it to view it somewhere else?

[image: Snapshot Devices Breakdown]

Comment: Now this view is completely hidden. No version info at all

Comment: @soshial I was still able to find this view just now, under Dashboard > "What is your audience like?" > Devices tab

Comment: Thanks. Now I can see it there again. Importantly, that it is under `Analytics Dashboard`

Answer (score 17):

It takes me time to find it. This is English image guide with step by step to view those Information for firebase

[image]

Or to have detail with number of devices, export csv to get this

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 15):

It's a bit tedious, but you can add a filter on the dashboard to see the usage numbers for each device and each iOS version. Click `Filters → User Property → Device Model` or `Filters → User Property → OS Version` to filter to a single device or OS.

If you record or export the numbers for each device and OS, you can work out the percentage distribution.

[image: Firebase filter options showing device models]

Comment: is it possible to see breakdown for device brand name; samsung, huawei, lg etc  ??

Answer (score 8):

With the new version of Firebase, you can see it by putting your mouse over the `other` section:
[image]

Comment: The problem with this as you can see in your screenshot is that it still shows 24% as “Other.” I was hoping to get a full breakdown.

Comment: I can't even make this happen

Answer (score 8):

You can also export a CSV[with a breakdown of the devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oiYf.png).  It is available from the Dashboard on the menu in upper-right.

Comment: Thanks! This is the only way I was able to see the full breakdown.