# View Device models for Event in Firebase Analytics

Tags: firebase, analytics, firebase-analytics

This is detail view of level_end event in Firebase Analytics.

[image: Event details]

I want to see all (or top 10) values of user properties, for example device_model (or custom user properies) for those users with whom the event happened.
Now I can see this information for gender, location, age.
For other properties I can only filtrate.

Is it possible to see other properties on Event detail view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the "Add filter" button on the top left next to the event name dropdown, and choose User Property. You can filter device_model there. After that, you can see how many event count for each model and see which one performs better. 
If you want to have a custom dashboard, I'd recommend to use BigQuery instead to aggregate and display custom query.

[image]

Comment: As I undestood, I can't view simple information like that without paid BigQuery?

Comment: Yeah, it's a paid feature. You can pay as you go though. I don't know a good  but free solution for your question.

Answer (score 3):

You can see the device model on Firebase Dashboard page, in the `Device` tab of the last card
[image: Firebase device list]

Comment: It's very frustrating that they don't let you see what's in the 68%. This data is basically useless

Comment: No, you can hover on the 68% https://stackoverflow.com/a/50817037/2870477

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you can use cohort analysis of the new web+app property of google analytics after linking your Firebase account

[image: cohort analysis screenshot]